# domain user accessing share as administrator

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2008, share, windows-server-2003, administration

I have very strange situation (can't find on the web), let me explain it:

In my network I have File Server(SERV1, Windows Server 2003) and Domain Controller with AD (SERV2, Windows Server 2008)

On the File Server there is shared folder with subfolders for each employee
TOPLEVELFOLDER > emp1, emp2, emp3... 
Each user has full control to only his own folder and read permission to other users' folders.

Share permissions on toplevelfolder look like this: SERV1\Administrators=full control, Authenticated Users=Change, Read

NTFS Security Settings: SERV1\Administrators=full, Everyone=read, SYSTEM=full, %MYDOMAINUSERNAME%=full

Every subfolder has all these settings inherited from toplevelfolder + full control for particular user.

All users in AD are from Domain Users group, NO ONE of these users are in Local Administrators group or in SERV1\Administrators group.

The problem is there are some users (absolutely no logic here) who has full access to all subfolders and files of toplevelfolder, when I look via SERV1 > Computer Management > Shared Folders > Sessions or Open Files then I see these users show ACCESSED BY ADMINISTRATOR, but other users show ACCESSED BY %DOMAINUSERNAME% as should be.

Before everything was fine, this problem occured on some random day.

I can't understand why some users authenticate as administrator.

Any ideas?
:)

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, here is the solution, it was born right after asking the question I struggled many day for now.

It appeared that I logged into that shared resource from random users' computers with my Domain Admin account and Windows remembered that account and password. Everything I needed to do is to remove remembered info.
First I run "control userpasswords2" from user's computer and saw the list is empty under Advanced > Manage Passwords then I run "control keymgr.dll" and VIOLA!!! here is the remembered info, simply removed it and the problem gone away :)

Maybe this practice/story will help others in the future too.
Thank you all!